# Create table failed in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, csv

I want to import [this csv file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/188HbjB8LabxlsXbWepqjzH-SYbYbabONWL0Yybywzws/edit#gid=214442224) to a SQLite database. Yet when I upload it i receive this error message without further explications:

[image]

I tried to upload it getting rid of the duplicates and with utf-8 and ascii encoding:

[image]

But still can't know what's the issue

Comment: Perhaps it's b/c the first column has no header (column name)?

Comment: @agileMike Yes, usually I ask not to import it

Comment: Are you saying, "Yes, I know and it's not the problem b/c I ask to not import it" or, "Yes, that worked?"

Comment: Also, you have to columns named ADDRESS. This will cause it to fail.

Comment: @agileMike Yes, I was saying _Yes, I know and it's not the problem b/c I ask to not import it_, sorry for not being ery clear :) I don't import the first column, address and city

Comment: Ok, could the problem be the two "address" columns? It causes it to fail in MS Sql.

Answer (score 0):

After exporting the spreadsheet to a CSV file:

```
sqlite> .mode csv

sqlite> .import schools-geocoded.csv schools

CREATE TABLE schools(...) failed: duplicate column name: address
sqlite>
```

"city" is also regarded as a duplicate.

After ensuring there are no duplicate names in the headers, the .import proceeds normally:

```
sqlite> .import schools-geocoded.csv schools

sqlite> .schema
.schema
CREATE TABLE schools(
  "" TEXT,
  "ATS_CODE" TEXT,
  "BORO" TEXT,
  "BORONUM" TEXT,
  "LOC_CODE" TEXT,
  "SCHOOLNAME" TEXT,
  "SCH_TYPE" TEXT,
  "MANAGED_BY" TEXT,
  "GEO_DISTRI" TEXT,
  "ADMIN_DIST" TEXT,
  "ADDRESS" TEXT,
  "STATE_CODE" TEXT,
  "ZIP" TEXT,
  "PRINCIPAL" TEXT,
  "PRIN_PH" TEXT,
  "FAX" TEXT,
  "GRADES" TEXT,
  "City" TEXT,
  "address2" TEXT,
  "block" TEXT,
  "city2" TEXT,
  "coordinates" TEXT,
  "county_fips" TEXT,
  "geocoded_address" TEXT,
  "id" TEXT,
  "is_exact" TEXT,
  "is_match" TEXT,
  "latitude" TEXT,
  "longitude" TEXT,
  "returned_address" TEXT,
  "side" TEXT,
  "state" TEXT,
  "state_fips" TEXT,
  "tiger_line" TEXT,
  "tract" TEXT,
  "zipcode" TEXT
);
sqlite>
```

Comment: Thanks, Tableplus tells me that it did imported succesfully but I can't see the tables in it.

Comment: Since there isn't a [TablePlus] tag on SO, maybe the problem should be brought to the attention of the vendor.